# Java Assign Class Values

Tags: java, class

It is a simple silly question but I don't know but how can I state the situation myself. Assume I have a class like this

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int value1;
  public void assignValue(int v1)

    {
        value1=v1;
    }
    public MyClass(int v1)
    {
        value1=v1;
    }
    public void write()
    {
        System.out.println("value1 :"+value1);
    }
}
```

If I run My Program like this

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //first
        MyClass c1 = new MyClass(10);
        MyClass c2 = new MyClass(20);
        c2 = c1;
        c1.assignValue(15);
        c1.write();
        c2.write();

       //but these are classes too.
       Integer d1 = 10;//also Integer d1 = new Integer(10); same
       Integer d2 = 20;
       d2 = d1;
       d1 = 15;
       System.out.println(d1);
       System.out.println(d2);
    }
}
```

Why c1 and c2 s values are equal and why not d1 and d2 are not(I have created from Integer Class an object)?

Comment: Integer objects are immutable.

Comment: When you do `c2 = c1` you make both variables refer to the same object. You don't reassign those variables after that, so they remain the same object. When you do `d2 = d1` you make both variables refer to the same object. But then `d1 = 15` makes `d1` refer to a different object.

Comment: what exactly do you think this: c2 = c1; does?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are always written in camelCase. That means they start with lowercase.

Comment: you are aware that `obj.method(value)` is totally different than `obj = value`? first one is calling a method of the instance pointed to by `obj`; second one is changing (replacing) the pointer to point to another instance (this actually is independent of being immutable or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `c2 = c1;` you are assingning the reference of the object.

When you do `d1 = 15;` you are essentially doing `d1=  new Integer(15)`. A new object is created and the reference of that held by d1. d2 is still referencing the old object (10)

Answer (score 2):

```
c2 = c1; // Both are pointing to same object

c1.AssignValue(15); // Value is being updated, not the actual reference.
```

Now, coming to the 2nd part of the code.

```
d2 = d1; // Both are pointing to same object

d1 = 15; // Reference object has been updated
```

But `d2` are still pointing to the old object.

Answer (score 1):

Here `c1.AssignValue(15);` you are changing value not the object reference, but `d1 = 15;` this will change the object reference.